# SphinxClient php подскажите как добавить сортировку по 2му полю

Tags: php, sphinx, sphinxsearch

ищу товары с помощью

```
  $sp = new SphinxClient();
  $sp->SetServer("localhost", 9312);

  $sp->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2);
  // как сюда добавить еще сортировку по доступности, чтобы сначала были товары доступные, а потом уже те что пока не доступны
  $sp->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_RELEVANCE, 'enabled DESC');
  $res = $sp->Query($keyword);
```

хотелось бы чтобы товары которые включены, были первыми, а потом уже отключенные товары